# State Clearing in Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm writing a program that asks a user for an integer > 0 which is used as the complexity factor for drawing a Koch curve. The program executes fine, once.  When running a second time the `Terminator` is invoked and the traceback points to what I think is the `aTurtle` variable not clearing it's last state. If I restart the kernel, and clear all outputs, it works fine again once, then the issue repeats.  What am I overlooking?

This was constructed and executed in `Jupyter` and tested in `qtconsole` as well.  Code is listed below:

```
import turtle
aTurtle = turtle.Turtle()

#Functions
def drawLS(aTurtle, instructions):
    for cmd in instructions:
        if cmd == 'F':
            aTurtle.forward(5)        
        elif cmd == '+':
            aTurtle.right(70)
        elif cmd == '-':
            aTurtle.left(70)
        else :
            print('Error : %s is an unknown command '%cmd)

def applyProduction():
    axiom = 'F'
    myRules = {'F': 'F-F++F-F'}
    for i in range(n):
        newString = ""
        for ch in axiom :
            newString = newString + myRules.get(ch, ch)
        axiom = newString
    return axiom

def lsystem():
    win = turtle.Screen()
    aTurtle.up()
    aTurtle.setposition(-200, 0)
    aTurtle.down()
    aTurtle.setheading(0)
    newRules = applyProduction()
    drawLS (aTurtle, newRules)
    win.exitonclick()

#Main
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter an integer greater than 0: "))
        break
    except:
        print ("Error, input was not an integer, please try again.")
if n < 1:
       print ("Error, input was not an integer greater than 0.")
else:
    lsystem()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't plan to survive a `win.exitonclick()` or any of the other turtle commands that turn control over to the tkinter event loop.  There are tricks for doing so but not worth the trouble when it's easier just to avoid this situation.  What you want is `win.clear()` or possibly `win.reset()`.  I've incorporated that below and rewrote your prompting logic to use it's own click event, instead of `exitonclick()`, and to use the graphic `numinput()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drawLS(turtle, instructions):
    for cmd in instructions:
        if cmd == 'F':
            turtle.forward(5)
        elif cmd == '+':
            turtle.right(70)
        elif cmd == '-':
            turtle.left(70)
        else:
            print('Error : %s is an unknown command '%cmd)

def applyProduction(n):
    axiom = 'F'
    myRules = {'F': 'F-F++F-F'}

    for _ in range(n):
        newString = ""
        for ch in axiom:
            newString += myRules.get(ch, ch)
        axiom = newString

    return axiom

def lsystem(n):
    aTurtle.up()
    aTurtle.setposition(-200, 0)
    aTurtle.down()
    aTurtle.setheading(0)
    newRules = applyProduction(n)
    drawLS(aTurtle, newRules)

def prompt(x=None, y=None):  # dummy arguments for onclick(), ignore them
    screen.onclick(None)

    n = screen.numinput("Complexity Factor", "Enter an integer greater than 0", minval=1, maxval=100)

    if n is not None:
        screen.clear()
        lsystem(int(n))

    screen.onclick(prompt)

screen = Screen()

aTurtle = Turtle()
aTurtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

prompt()

screen.mainloop()
```

When the drawing finishes, click on the screen to get a new prompt for a different complexity factor and a new drawing.

Comment: Ok, so I see the code purely ignores n if it is a positive non-integer but allows you to click the screen again. Would I be able to use try/except with the prompting you listed to keep asking for an integer like it does when entering a value lower than 1?  Also is the underscore in the for statement another way to declare a counter without assigning a variable there?

Comment: @P-Sides, the `numinput()` method has its own logic to handle some of the deviant cases -- since I set 1 as a minimum we can expect a positive number or `None`, never a negative.  It does of course return a `float` so we have to deal with that.  The underscore is a valid Python variable which by *convention* we use as a "don't care" variable.  Here we want the loop to run but don't need the counter.  (When using Python interactively, the underscore always contains the result of the last expression you entered.)

Comment: Ok thank you, this satisfies the original intent of the small program.